# How to run Maven surefire without printing out test results to the command line?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running the Maven 3.1.0 [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) **already** with the `--quiet` option, however it still prints out the results of unit tests out to the command line, even if they all pass. **Is there a way to only get it to print failures?**

The output I'd like to suppress if everything is fine looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running net.initech.project.dawgs.actionfactory.InterfaceActionFactoryTest
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.425 sec
Running net.initech.project.dawgs.actionfactory.ValueScopeTest
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running net.initech.project.dawgs.assertion.AssertContainsTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec
Running net.initech.project.assertion.AssertEndsWithTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec
Running net.initech.project.assertion.AssertIsEqualTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running net.initech.project.assertion.AssertIsLikeTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec
Running net.initech.project.assertion.AssertStartsWithTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec

Results :

Tests run: 52, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

No, I do not want to pipe the output to `/dev/null`

Comment: Glad someone asked this. I wish maven defaults didn't produce this diarrhea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the `surefire.printSummary` property to `false`: [this should only print the test cases that have errors.](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#printSummary) So try running it as `mvn -q -Dsurefire.printSummary=false`.

Alternatively, you can put it in your pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>            
      <printSummary>false</printSummary> 
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This still prints the "----<br>TESTS----<br>" banner, any idea how to get rid of that? I'm tempted to file that as a feature request against SureFire since it seems it ought to be included in that option.

Comment: One more caveat that fooled me: if your command has `-Dsurefire.useFile=false`, then the setting of `-Dsurefire.printSummary=false` will not be respected.

Comment: Another caveat - inside a `pluginManagement` element this setting seems to get ignored.

Comment: And another caveat - if you have printSummary=false, then  `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` will not be respected