# How to disable console logs on executing mvn clean test

Tags: java, maven, testng

How can I disable printing of below console logs after executing "mvn clean test"?

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
ClientTest.SalesForce_CreateContact_Keyword_3(ClientTest)
  Run 1: PASS
  Run 2: PASS
  Run 3: PASS
  Run 4: PASS
  Run 5: PASS
  Run 6: PASS


Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Going with given below duplicate marked solution didn't work. Results: Failed tests:.... are still getting printed whenever there is atleast one failure.

[How to run Maven surefire without printing out test results to the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489112/how-to-run-maven-surefire-without-printing-out-test-results-to-the-command-line)

Comment: `mvn clean test > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: If you mean disabling the debug info for the execution, why would you want to do it?